# Ubuntu suspend doesn't work

Tags: suspend

Notebook HP Omen 15-en00xx. AMD 7 4800H/ RTX2060, Win10 + Ubuntu 21.04, nvidia driver-460, external monitor.

Steps: Power off -> suspend -> 5-7 sec display is black and login form. After logging is the clean system without early opened programs.

I remember similar problem on previous laptop - win10 and ubuntu 18. In that case Ubuntu didn't have a suspend mode in the list under "power off" menu and I found solution related to disabling hybernate mode in Windows (I can be incorrect here). I want to try that solution but can't find it now.

Comment: Just to confirm: when you resume from suspend, all of your applications are closed. This is the problem you want to fix, yes?

Comment: @matigo Thank you for the answer. There are 2 related (I suppose) problems - 1) the laptop don't really sleep in "suspend" mode  (coolers work) and "wake up" (reload) after 5-7 sec independently. 2) All programs are closed after wake up from this broken suspend mode.

Comment: Get more info with `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` within 4 minutes of a suspend attempt

Comment: Does `free` show any swap space?

Answer (score 1):

I fix this problem in two actions:

1. I upgrade bios from F.7 to F.15 (from win10).
2. After restarting Ubuntu lost RTX video adapter (the external monitor doesn't work with AMD in my case). Also About -> Graphics section showed only AMD video adapter. I installed Nvidia driver 470 instead of 460 with enrolling changes in grub. Now suspend mode works perfectly.